# Is it possible to encrypt password in 'mods-enabled/sql' file in freeradius 3.0.x?

Tags: freeradius

I installed the freeradius package on Ubuntu 18.04.

The version of freeradius was installed with 3.0.16. And database installed mariaDB.

The contents of the 'mods-enabled/sql' file:

```
...
server = "localhost"
port = 3306
login = "radius"
password = "mypassword"   #I want to encrypt this.
...
```

Is there a way to encrypt  "mypassword"?

Answer (score 1):

No.  FreeRADIUS provides no support for encrypted passwords in configuration files.  This is the same as the majority of other daemons.